# Rshiny Sending an Email with mailR | jCall Error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rjava

Below is the `mailR` code I have running on the server side of an RShiny app that I am building. The aim of this app is to send an email when a certain occurrence happens in the financial markets. When I run this code on its own in a separate script (not in a RShiny app) it runs fine. When run in the RShiny app, the app crashes with the error below.

```
sender <- "FROM@gmail.com"
  recipients <- c("TO@gmail.com")
  body.string <- "words words words words words punchline"
  send.mail(from = sender,
            to = recipients,
            subject = "***STOPLOSS ALERT***",
            body = body.string,
            smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                        user.name = "FROM@gmail",            
                        passwd = "******", ssl = TRUE),
            authenticate = TRUE,
            send = TRUE)
```

Error Message:

```
Warning in if (file.exists(body)) body <- readChar(body, file.info(body)$size) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning: Error in .jcall: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the given parameters
Stack trace (innermost first):
    56: <Anonymous>
    55: stop
    54: .jcheck
    53: .jcall
    52: .jrcall
    51: email$setMsg
    50: send.mail
    43: isolate
    42: server [C:\Users\****/app.R#135]
     1: runApp
    Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the given parameters
```

Since the code works fine on its own, outside of the Shiny app, my thinking is that RShiny is somehow causing this to bug out on the lower level Java code. Any advice/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you put your code in a shiny-app skeleton, so we just have to adapt the mail-params? Like that its very hard to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try executing a simple code like below and tell me if you are still getting any error?

```
library(mailR)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
   actionButton("sendMail","Send Mail")

   )

server <- function(input, output) {
   observeEvent(input$sendMail,
                {
                  sender <- "FROM@gmail.com"
                  recipients <- c("TO@gmail.com")
                  body.string <- "words words words words words punchline"
                  send.mail(from = sender,
                            to = recipients,
                            subject = "***STOPLOSS ALERT***",
                            body = body.string,
                            smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                                        user.name = "FROM@gmail",            
                                        passwd = "******", ssl = TRUE),
                            authenticate = TRUE,
                            send = TRUE)
                }
   )
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Sahasrahudhe I tried your code, it worked well. What if I have different receivers, and I want to let them input their email address and get their own feedback email? how do I specify the to= part?